# I have Two Dropdownlist but Only one dropdownlist value should get insert into database

Tags: c#, asp.net

In this code Else Part alone working even if i select  dropdownlist2.

```
string Varddl;

if(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()== null )
{

   Varddl = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;

}
else
{
   Varddl = DropDownList3.SelectedItem.Text;
}

string OIMSquery="Insert into tablename values('" + varddl + "')";
```

Comment: Not sure, but shouldn't this `DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString()== null` be `DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text.ToString() != null` (you check if it is NOT NULL then take value)

Answer (score 1):

You will never get null after calling `ToString()` and condition will never come true and always `else` part of if will execute, you probably need to compare it with empty string.

```
if(DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text == "")
```

Answer (score 1):

put condition like this>>

```
if(DropDownList2.SelectedItem== null )
{
    .
    .
}
else
{
}
```

It will work.